# Why does the List rows have a black background?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a simple view in SwiftUI that contains a text field, a button and then a list beneath the button that displays the results of an API call.  Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct MealsByNameView: View {
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State var recipeForName: [RecipeModel] = []
    @State var searchButtonClicked: Bool = false
    @State var mealByName: String = ""
    let api = API()
    
    var backgroundColor: Color {
        if colorScheme == .dark {
            return Color(.systemGray5)
        } else {
            return Color(.systemGray6)
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                HeaderView(headerTitle: "Search for Recipes by Name", fontSize: 24.0, backgroundColor: .white, textColor: .black)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .padding(.leading, 25)
                    TextField("Search for a Recipe by Name", text: $mealByName)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 40)
                        .onChange(of: mealByName) {
                            print($0)
                        }
                    
                    if !mealByName.isEmpty {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                            .imageScale(.medium)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray3))
                            .padding(3)
                            .padding(.trailing, 5)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    self.mealByName = ""
                                    self.searchButtonClicked = false
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(12)
                .padding(.top, 30)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                
                Button(action: {
                    let recipeByName: String = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=\(self.mealByName)"
                    api.loadRecipeData(url: recipeByName) { (recipes) in
                        self.recipeForName = recipes
                        self.searchButtonClicked = true
                    }
                }
                ) {
                    Text("Search for Recipe")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 40)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .background(Color("palette_pink"))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8.0)
                }
                
                if self.searchButtonClicked {
                    List(recipeForName, id: \.idMeal) { recipe in
                        HStack {
                            WebImage(url: URL(string:recipe.mealThumbnailImage))
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                                .cornerRadius(12.0)
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8.0) {
                                Text(recipe.idMeal)
                                Text(recipe.mealName)
                            }
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(Color.white)
            .padding(.top, 75)
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

//MARK: - PREVIEW
struct MealsByNameView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MealsByNameView()
    }
}
```

It ends up looking like this:

[image]

Simply, I want the list to have the same background color as the rest of the view (ie. white).  I cannot understand why it's black.

Please advise?
Jason

Comment: are u sure your dark mode is not active?

Comment: @swiftPunk Yes, you were right.  I had Appearance set to "Dark" in my info.plist.  Thank you!